# How to create a vertically and horizontally centred title page

Tags: formatting

Could anyone help me make my title page for a report centred both vertically and horizontally, i.e. directly in the middle of its own page.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{RAF Application}
\author{Edward Rolls, Eli Bingham, Laurence Hutton-Smith}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} 

\maketitle

% abstract
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
```

Where at the end of the code the main content begins, any help would be greatly appreciated, this really shouldn't be that hard but for some reason I can't work it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to redefine the `\@maketitle` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vfil
\begingroup
\let\footnote\thanks
\centering
{\LARGE\@title}\vskip1.5em
{\large\@author}\vskip1em
{\large\@date}
\endgroup
\vfil
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Added '\vskip1em' to {\large\@date} to centre that, but otherwise great! Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The alignement of the date is what came to my mind when i left the library today. A simple `\par` after the "date"-group adresses this too.

Answer (score 3):

You said report, but using `article` class. It is bit confusing as to why don't you use `report` class for typesetting a report.

For `article` class you can pass the `titlepage` option to make the title centered. You need not put `\maketitle` inside the `titlepage` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%\usepackage{fullpage}%% obsolete don't use. Use geometry package instead.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}  %% showframe is just tfor demo, remove in your file  
%
\title{RAF Application}
\author{Edward Rolls, Eli Bingham, Laurence Hutton-Smith}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% abstract
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, except all the lines around the edges seem to spoil the appearance, thank you very much for your time though!

Comment: @Freeman Those lines are there just to show that everything is centered. Remove `showframe` from geometry and they vanish. I feel that it is better to have abstract in the second page though (like in my code).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing there are a million ways to do it. I would probably patch the `\@maketitle` macro to get the centering.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage}{\newpage\vspace*{\fill}}{}{}
\appto{\@maketitle}{\vspace{\fill}}
\preto{\abstract}{\vspace{-\fill}}
\appto{\endabstract}{\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatother
```